# Почему не выполняется ruby-файл в VS Code во вкладке "Вывод"?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

В VS Code установлены Ruby и Code Runner.

При выполнении файла появляется надпись во вкладке вывода: `[Running] ruby "d:\Web\code\yourname.rb"`, но сам файл не выполняется. Но если выполнить файл в терминале, то всё будет работать. Почему так?

Код файла:

`puts "hello"
 name = gets.chomp
 puts "hello #{name}!"`

Скриншоты:
[image: Вкладка "Вывод"]
[image: Терминал]

Comment: А там ввод возможен? И он точно "не выполняется", а не "выполняется, но ничего не выводит"? Если последнее, то должно помочь добавление в начало `STDOUT.sync = true`.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Но действительно ввод там невозможен.

Comment: Грустно. Окей, объяснил в ответе, чем это вызвано и как решение работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В добавление к предыдущему ответу, в VS Code в настройках есть параметр:

**Параметры** -> **Run Code Configuration** -> **code-runner.runInTerminal**.

По умолчанию он false. если его установить в true, то код будет запускаться во встроенном терминале. В терминале и ввод возможен и вывод работает.

Для удобства можно ещё параметр **code-runner.clearPreviousOutput** установить в true

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что вывод **буфферизованный**. Отдельные порции накапливаются в буфер и в некоторые моменты буфер сбрасывается в реальный вывод.

Можно включить **принудительный сброс буфера вывода после каждой операции**, за это отвечает [атрибут `IO#sync`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-sync) (методы `sync` и `sync=`). `puts` выводит в стандартный вывод, поэтому переключить его нужно у `STDOUT`:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
```

Как для него выбирается значение по умолчанию, к сожалению, я не в курсе. Подозреваю, что не без помощи [метода `IO#tty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-tty-3F).

---

Вот только ввод туда, как вы сами заметили, невозможен.

Comment: D-side, добрый вечер. Помоги с вопросом, если не трудно   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790725/nodejs-Как-правильно-настроить-роутинг