# Можно ли взять данные из адресной строки и передать их в ajax запрос? без node.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5

В строку передаются данные: `sait.ru/sale.html?sale_id=1`

Для того, чтобы при переходе на эту страницу, ***ajax-ом*** подхватить данные из адресной строки, и использовать их в `data`: в ***ajax*** запросе. А уже из `json - ответа` в `ajax` запросе вывести данные.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Или есть более удобные способы передачи данных со страницы на страницу ***(только HTML и JS)***, помимо `localStorage`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [NodeJs Как правильно настроить роутинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790725/nodejs-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)

Comment: @user8719712 Если ответ вас устроил, отметьте его решенным пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примеры js кода для получения данных

```
document.location.href       http://domain.ru/saytostroy/?page=4#top
document.location.protocol   http:
document.location.host       domain.ru
document.location.pathname   /saytostroy/
document.location.search     ?page=4
document.location.hash       #top
```

Пример ajax запроса с библиотекой Jquery

```
var url = document.location.href
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    `dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://domain.ru/server.php",
    data:{'page' : hash},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```